# Move div along all body width

Tags: jquery, html

I have to move a picture along the whole lenght of my body. So this is the code I wrote:

```
function moveRight(){
   $("#b").animate({left: "+=400"}, $("body").width(),moveLeft)
}

function moveLeft(){
   $("#b").animate({left: "-=400"}, $("body").width(),moveRight)
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   moveRight();
});
```

You can find a working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mm9em/1/). I am using a random picture in the fiddle, but as you can see it goes out of the screen.

I would like to to stop before the end of the body (on the right). How could I do it?

Comment: Well, you never define anywhere were it should stop animating. The second parameter is either duration or options (which is an object).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compute the `left` parameter value using the **parent** and the **image container** widths:

```
function moveRight(){
   $("#b").animate({
       left: $("#b").parent().width() - $("#b").width()
     },
     $("body").width(),
     moveLeft
   );
}
```

And for the left side you can use `0` instead.

```
function moveLeft(){
    $("#b").animate({left: "0"}, $("body").width(),moveRight)
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mm9em/2/)

Comment: Just a thing: can I also define how fast should it run?

Comment: @AlbertoRossi Sure, use `duration` field in the object from first parameter. `$(...).animate({left: ..., duration: 1000}, ...)` - where `1000` means one second (`1000 ms`). Read more [in the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Answer (score 1):

instead of doing a static `400px` you could `$('body').width() - 200`

200 being the width of your image.